# Messing around on your phone or with your phone?

Tags: differences, prepositions

I have a lot of work to do but I'm just spending a whole day fiddling with my phone. And a friend asks me what I am doing right now. I answer: "I'm just messing around on/with my phone."

Which one is correct? If both are correct, is there any difference? Also If there are any more natural and idiomatic ways to say it, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want “on,” but “with” is not wrong either; it just means something else.

If you’re messing around with, say, an app that happens to be on your phone, then your phone is the **platform** on which you’re messing around, so you’d use “on.”

On the other hand, if the thing you are messing around with is the phone itself (e.g. modifying the hardware, changing some settings, or building a jetpack into it), the phone becomes the **object** with which you are messing around, so you’d use “with.”

A third alternative would be if you were using your phone to mess around (e.g. prank calling people), in which case the phone is the **tool** with which you’re messing around. You’d also use “with” here.

Comment: This seems correct, except I think the second paragraph is perhaps a bit too literal. You don’t need to be adding jet packs to your phone (great idea, though!) for _with_ to be usable to me: if you’re fiddling with your phone settings or trying to install an app or changing your lock screen, for example, I’d call that messing around with your phone as well.

Comment: Can I call it messing around with my phone as well if I'm going on social medias and texting friends and playing games?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Great point! As long as the object of focus for messing around is the phone itself, it doesn’t have to be physical. I’ll edit my post to mention it! P.S. The jetpack idea was an obscure reference.

Comment: @You Yes, please see the second paragraph.